# Discord.js Rich embed probleme

Tags: node.js, discord.js

It doesn't send

```
 let kEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
     .setDescription(`~Kick~`)
     .setColor("#e56b00")
     .addField('**Kicked User: **`' , `${kUser} with ID ${kUser.id}` , '`', false)
     .addField('**Kicked by: **`' , `<@${msg.author.id}> with ID ${msg.author.id}` , '`', false)
     .addField('**Kicked in the **`' , msg.channel , " channel" ,'`', false)
     .addField('**Reason: **`' , `${kReason}` , '`',false);
   let ecto = msg.guild.channels.find(`name`, "mod-logs")
   if (!ecto) {msg.channel.send("Couldn't find channel")}

   msg.guild.member(kUser).kick(kReason)
   ecto.send(kEmbed)
```

and i gives the following error

```
app[worker.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
app[worker.1]: embed.fields[0].inline: Must be either true or false.
app[worker.1]: embed.fields[1].inline: Must be either true or false.
app[worker.1]: embed.fields[2].inline: Must be either true or false.
app[worker.1]: embed.fields[3].inline: Must be either true or false.
```

Please help please I am using Discord.JS and i dont know why it's not working and it doesnt crash it just doesnt send the embed there is more code but it works and it does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addField` method takes 3 arguments `name`, `value` and optional `inline`, your code is passing more than 2 `string` arguments which is incorrect. corrected `kEmbed` variable should look something like this

```
let kEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
     .setDescription(`~Kick~`)
     .setColor("#e56b00")
     .addField('**Kicked User: **`' , `${kUser} with ID ${kUser.id}` + '`', false)
     .addField('**Kicked by: **`' , `<@${msg.author.id}> with ID ${msg.author.id}` + '`', false)
     .addField('**Kicked in the **`' , `${msg.channel} channel` + '`', false)
     .addField('**Reason: **`' , `${kReason}` + '`',false);
```